# ElasticSearch: Query syntax is painful

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I just have started working on ElasticSearch and it is painful to write in Painless. So difficult to see the connections between brackets, too many spaces. I am working on the outlier detection and as an example, this is what the code looks like:

```html
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "hour": {
            "gte": "{{start}}",
            "lte": "{{end}}"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "metrics": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "metric",
        "size": 5
      },
      "aggs": {
        "queries": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "query",
            "size": 500
          },
          "aggs": {
            "series": {
              "date_histogram": {
                "field": "hour",
                "interval": "hour"
              },
              "aggs": {
                "avg": {
                  "avg": {
                    "field": "value"
                  }
                },
                "movavg": {
                  "moving_avg": {
                    "buckets_path": "avg",
                    "window": 24,
                    "model": "simple"
                  }
                },
                "surprise": {
                  "bucket_script": {
                    "buckets_path": {
                      "avg": "avg",
                      "movavg": "movavg"
                    },
                    "script": "(avg - movavg).abs()"
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "largest_surprise": {
              "max_bucket": {
                "buckets_path": "series.surprise"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "ninetieth_surprise": {
          "percentiles_bucket": {
            "buckets_path": "queries>largest_surprise",
            "percents": [
              90
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

I solve it by creating my own convention for the code in order for it to be readable. It is based only on the closing parenthesis and the indentation helps in readability. It just opens a new line whenever it finds a closing brackets' group (except the ones inline like "{{start}}") It is something like this:

```html
{
"query":{"filtered":{"filter":{"range":{"hour":{"gte":"{{start}}","lte":"{{end}}"}}}}},                                                                                 
"size":0,
"aggs":{"metrics":{"terms":{"field":"metric",“size”:5},
      "aggs":{"queries":{"terms":{"field":"query","size":500},
            "aggs":{"series": {"date_histogram":{"field":"hour","interval":"hour"},
                           "aggs":{"avg":{"avg":{"field":"value"}},
                                                                      ....
```

I would love to know whether there is any other convention which helps in readability and to follow the lines of code. What is being used in the community?

CODE from: https://www.elastic.co/blog/implementing-a-statistical-anomaly-detector-part-1

Comment: Writing your query in the [Kibana Console](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/console-kibana.html) allows you to keep it nice and tidy since you can use automatic indenting... Just saying...

Comment: I am not searching for a formatting tool, but something to help in readability and to follow the code. In Kibana the code has the same format, it is still difficult to read. Or maybe because I am just starting it seems so.

Comment: Properly indenting your code (which is not the case in your sample query above) is the first step to readability.

Comment: Sorry, it is the editor of StackOverflow. The code is indented in the source that I am using. I will format it now. Also check the source.

Comment: ok, never mind, that probably means you have a mix of spaces and tabs in your indenting

Comment: Anyway, JSON is the way it is, there's not much to do to make it more readable, you simply need to get used to it and read/write lots of it, that'll eventually become second nature

Comment: i don't understand, do you mean the DSL is painful? The only script i see is : `(avg - movavg).abs()`

Comment: I meant that the structure of the text is too all over the place. @K_U.

Comment: I dont think that DSL is painful. Though what is real painful is the painless scripts..